# Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound) in Phusion Passenger environment

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Running RailsEnv using Phusion Passenger.

```
==> ruby -v 
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

==> rails -v 
Rails 4.1.0

==> rake --version
rake, version 10.4.2
```

But after running rails new  and opening site in browser, I get the following error

```
Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make the error go away by packing the gems into vendor/bundle by running the following from my app folder

bundle install --path vendor/bundle